# KSOAP2-Android SoapEnvelope Errors / Questions

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I'm attempting to make a soap call using ksoap2-android the server is expecting a soap request to look like this below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<soapenv:Body>
<hilo:getHLPredAndMetadata xmlns:hilo="http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/axis/webservices/highlowtidepred/wsdl">
  <stationId xmlns="">8454000</stationId> 
  <beginDate xmlns="">20060920 00:00</beginDate> 
  <endDate xmlns="">20060922 23:59</endDate> 
  <datum xmlns="">0</datum> 
  <unit xmlns="">0</unit> 
  <timeZone xmlns="">0</timeZone> 
  </hilo:getHLPredAndMetadata>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

But after adding properties I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header /> 
<v:Body>
<n0:getHLPredAndMetadata id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/axis/webservices/highlowtidepred/wsdl">
  <stationId i:type="d:string">8722669</stationId> 
  <beginDate i:type="d:string">20101101 00:00</beginDate> 
  <endDate i:type="d:string">20101101 23:00</endDate> 
  <datum i:type="d:int">0</datum> 
  <unit i:type="d:int">0</unit> 
  <timeZone i:type="d:int">0</timeZone> 
  </n0:getHLPredAndMetadata>
  </v:Body>
  </v:Envelope>
```

The Source is pretty straight foward.  After making the call I get an error below:

```
11-02 03:01:01.151: ERROR/NoaaTideSoap(389): unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44eff1b8) 
11-02 03:01:01.151: ERROR/NoaaTideSoap(389): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44eff1b8)
11-02 03:01:01.151: ERROR/NoaaTideSoap(389):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:245)
11-02 03:01:01.151: ERROR/NoaaTideSoap(389):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:1365)
11-02 03:01:01.151: ERROR/NoaaTideSoap(389):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
11-02 03:01:01.151: ERROR/NoaaTideSoap(389):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
11-02 03:01:01.151: ERROR/NoaaTideSoap(389):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
```

I'm not sure weather I am getting this error because of a KSOAP issue.  I cannot see a response coming back from the service i am calling.

My thought is that the service is expecing a prefix "hilo" like they specify here:

and and where my call looks like:

Additionally in the properties they expect:

8454000

and again the attibutes are different

8722669

Does anyone know how to set these values using KSOAP?

Below is a code snip:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

  request.addProperty("stationId","8722669");
  request.addProperty("beginDate","20101101 00:00");
  request.addProperty("endDate","20101101 23:00");
  request.addProperty("datum",0);
  request.addProperty("unit",0);
  request.addProperty("timeZone",0);

  SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  //soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
  soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

  AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
  aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>");

  aht.debug = true;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of things:

1. The namespace being called hilo or n0 does not make a difference for the server.
2. I think there is some other issue with your response parsing. You should set your transport debug to true.

androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

and then debug on the getResponse call and see what you get. You should have a SoapObject or SoapPrimitive or SoapFault that contains the repsonse from the server. With the debug option to true you will also see the raw xml of the response in bodyIn. That should allow you to figure whats up.

Answer (score 0):

If the web service is .NET based, place a breakpoint first or simply set a log message to see whether the web service is invoked properly .

Another thing I would suggest is that you use a complex object as a parameter instead of having all these parameters you are sending.